# Need an advise with Power Bi function DATEADD

Tags: powerbi, dateadd

How can i create mesure like that:
If email_name = '1' add 4 days to some_value , If email_name = '2' to some_value.

So i think the idea is clear.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Because I imagine you are wanting to do an IF condition row-by-row, you'd be much better served by creating a *calculated column* as opposed to a *measure*. In any case, your DAX for the calculated column would look something like this:

```
New Col =
SWITCH(
    [email_name],
    '1', [some_date_value] + 4,
    '2', [some_date_value] + ?, // Your statement was not clear here...
    <value to return in all other cases here>
)
```

I recommend a SWITCH statement here so as to aviod the nuisance of building nested IF statements. Keep in mind that your `[some_date_value]` column will need to be the data type of date or numeric so that Power BI can add the days.